# map::lower_bound() equivalent for python's dict class?

Tags: python, stl

I am writing some code that requires me to fetch the lower bound of a key (for simplicity, ignore keys that lie below the smallest key in the collection).

In C++, using std::map (as the most comparable data type) I would simply use the lower_bound() to return the iterator.

My Pythonfoo is not that great, but I am guessing that (in case Python does not already have a way of doing this), this would be a good use of a lambda function ...

What is the Pythonic way of retrieving the lower bound key for a given index?

In case the question is too abstract, this is what I am actually trying to do:

I have a Python dict indexed by date. I want to be able to use a date to look up the dict, and return the value associated with the lowerbound of the specified key.

Snippet follows:

```
mymap = { datetime.date(2007, 1, 5): 'foo',
          datetime.date(2007, 1, 10): 'foofoo',
          datetime.date(2007, 2, 2): 'foobar',
          datetime.date(2007, 2, 7): 'foobarbar' }

mydate = datetime.date(2007, 1, 7)

# fetch lbound key for mydate from mymap
def mymap_lbound_key(orig):
    pass # return the lbound for the key
```

I don't really want to loop through the keys, looking for the first key <= provided key, unless there is no better alternative ...

Answer (score 8):

Python's `dict` class doesn't have this functionality; you'd need to write it yourself. It sure would be convenient if the keys were already sorted, wouldn't it, so you could do a binary search on them and avoid iterating over them all? In this vein, I'd have a look at the `sorteddict` class in the `blist` package. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/

Answer (score 8):

if you have date somehow overloaded that it can compare things look into the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#module-bisect).

a minimal integer coding example:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

data = {
    200 : -100,
    -50 : 0,
    51 : 100,
    250 : 200
}

keys = list(data.keys())

print data[  keys[ bisect_left(keys, -79) ]  ]
```

Answer (score 5):

When I want something that resembles a c++ map, I use SortedDict.  You can use `irange` to get an iterator over items greater than a given key--which I think is how `std::lower_bound` works.

code:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
sd = SortedDict()
sd[105] = 'a'
sd[102] = 'b'
sd[101] = 'c'

#SortedDict is sorted on insert, like std::map
print(sd)

# sd.irange(minimum=<key>) returns an iterator beginning with the first key not less than <key>
print("min = 100", list(sd.irange(minimum=100)))
print("min = 102", list(sd.irange(minimum=102)))
print("min = 103", list(sd.irange(minimum=103)))
print("min = 106", list(sd.irange(minimum=106)))
```

output:

```
SortedDict(None, 1000, {101: 'c', 102: 'b', 105: 'a'})
min = 100 [101, 102, 105]
min = 102 [102, 105]
min = 103 [105]
min = 106 []
```

Comment: I don't want to create a list; just want to find out how "far" the iterator returned by `sd.irange(minimum=<key>)` is, from the beginning.  In C++, I would do something like `sd.lower_bound(key)-sd.begin()`.  Is there a way to do _that_?  Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Does `next(sd.irange(minimum=103)) - sd.keys()[0]` do what you want? It finds the difference between the first key above the bound and the first key. In this case that's 105 - 101 = 4. If so, keep in mind that `next()` will thow a StopIteration exception if no items are greater than the bound.

Comment: Thank you! Also, is there a "strategy" to solve such problems in Python which can typically be solved in C++ using a red black tree (std::map)?  Your method works, but all this seems more like a "hack" and not an idiomatic Pythonic thing to do, hence my question.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say "probably".  The python ecosystem has many nooks and crannies.  But my path has taken me away from trees and towards more general structures like directed graphs, so I don't really know which nook or cranny to recommend for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what the "lower bound" is: The latest date before/after the query date?

Anyway since a dict doesn't impose an inherent order on its keys, you need a different structure. Store your keys in some structure that keeps them sorted and allows fast searches.

The simplest solution would be to just store the dates *sorted* in a list of (date, value), and do a binary search to zoom in on the region you want. If you need/want better performance, I think a b-tree is what you need.