# Is there a multiset's equal_range in python like in C++11?

Tags: python, c++

I C++11 I can do following:

```
multiset<int> ms {1,2,4,6,3,2,2,1}; // set will sort these elements automatically

std::pair<multiset<int>::iterator, multiset<int>::iterator> bounds;

// look for number 2 in the multiset
bounds = ms.equal_range(2);

for (auto v: ms)
{
    cout << v << " ";
}
```

It gives 2 2 2 as there are three 2's in the multiset. How to do same in python?

I can do set only like this:  ms  = {1,2,4,6,3,2,2,1}. This set will sort the elements as well, but also removes duplicates. If I cant use set, is there other data structure for that?

Also what is equivalent of this `ms.equal_range(2);` to search for multiple elements in python, like in c++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Python equivalent for C++ "multiset<int>"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346905/is-there-a-python-equivalent-for-c-multisetint)

Comment: I saw this anwser, but it does not explain how to simulate equal_range in python.

Comment: Please reword your question then. Also, refrain from asking multiple questions in one.

Comment: I changed the tittle. thx.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343739/maplower-bound-equivalent-for-pythons-dict-class) question asks about `std::lower_bound`. Since `std::equal_range` is `[std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound)`, the answer should be relevant.

Answer (score -1):

This is for lists not sets, however the .count method might be what you're looking for.

Quoting the documentation:
list.count(x)
Return the number of times x appears in the list.
end quote.

So for example.

```
two_three = [2, 4, 5, 2, 2]
print two_three.count(2)
=> 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but dont want count. I want like equal_range that gives pointers to first and last elements of item that I search.

Comment: Sorry to down vote, but your second code does not make sense. The count of 2 in the set is 1. Always 1.

Comment: How about using id() on the first and last element then.

Comment: You're right @Marcin , my mistake i'll edit the comment. I apoligize.