# Maintain ordered list in Python with O(logN) lookup/insertion?

Tags: python, unordered-map

How to maintain a list with O(logN) lookup and insertion in Python?

In C++ I will simply use `std::map`. Any equivalent in Python library?

ps, I need equivalent for `std::map::lower_bound()`.

For example, suppose I have

```
((0, x), (0.5, y), (1.5, z))
```

I want to lookup `0.3` and return `(0,x)`, lookup `0.5` and return `(0.5, y)`

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343739/maplower-bound-equivalent-for-pythons-dict-class) answer?

Comment: @idjaw you have 10K+ rep, you can close questions for being duplicates.

Comment: @Soviut No. You need a gold badge in the specific tag. In this case it would be Python (or even unordered-map...but Python would be more realistic), which I don't have yet.

Comment: You can use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to get the insertion point in a sorted list, but insertion will still be O(n). Lookup is O(log n) as in `lower_bound`.

Comment: You can do `O(log n)` insertion and lookup with a balanced binary tree, such as a red-black tree.